# I want to show all the tables of sql names in combobox

Tags: c#

I want to show all the table names of a MySQL database in a combobox and there rows in another combobox of selected tables from the first combobox.

```
    string cmdstr = "select * from sys.tables";
    string conStr = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-63RVRDI\IBRAHIMDATABASE;Initial Catalog=Sample_DataBase;Integrated Security=True"
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr,conStr);

    try
    {
        sda.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataTables tbl in dt.DataTables)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(tbl[1]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Please ask your question more specific. you didn't mentioned what is your problem exactly.

Comment: `SqlDataAdapter` is for the Microsoft **SQL Server** database - **not** MySQL ..... so are you using **MySQL**, or (MS) **SQL Server**? Please update your question and add an appropriate database tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to display the table columns in the second combo box. If that is the case please try the below code.

Load tables

```
        string cmdstr = "SELECT * FROM sys.Tables";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr, connectionString);
        sda.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            cboTables.Items.Add(row["name"]);
        }
```

Now add a SelectedIndexChanged event for the tables combobox and add the below code.

```
        cboColumns.Items.Clear();
        string cmdstr = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + cboTables.Text + "' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr, connectionString);
        sda.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            cboColumns.Items.Add(row["COLUMN_NAME"]);
        }
        cboColumns.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Hope this helps.